# What would be the max number of people who could reach a score of at least 30 for this card game.

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-optimization, card-games

You're a teacher, you have a standard deck of cards with 2 jokers, so 54 cards in total. You distribute the cards equally amongst your 18 students, resulting in 3 cards per student. they can only have 3 cards at a time.

Each type of card is assigned a different number of points:

Joker - 0

Ace - 1

(2-10) - Respective values

Jack - 11

Queen - 12

King - 13

If you have a pair you are given 5 bonus points. E g. 5,5,6 = 5+5+6+5(bonus)

A triple is 10 bonus points. Ex. 6,6,6 = 6+6+6+10(bonus)

The goal is for students to reach a score of 30 or more. Students can trade cards to reach that goal but they all have to have exactly 3 cards at all times.

The question is, what is the maximum amount of students that can reach a score of 30 or more?

Also me and my friend tried calculating this and we got the max as 10 winners and 8 losers.

the 10 winners would be

- K+6+6
- Q+7+7
- J+7+7
- 10+8+8
- 9+8+8
- 8+9+9
- 6+10+10
- 4+J+J
- 2+Q+Q
- K+K+K

Comment: Can you state the way that you got 10 winners? Ideally, even explain why you can't easily swap to get 11 winners.  That's a way for you to show your work.

Comment: Well first I found each combination of 3 cards that gets above 30.
So all triples above 7
And the pairs too 
Would you like a list of those?

K+6+6

Q+7+7

J+7+7

10+8+8

9+8+8

8+9+9

7+9+9

6+10+10

5+10+10

4+J+J

3+J+J

2+Q+Q

1+Q+Q

theres the list of pairs

Comment: Can you clean up the list so there is no "smaller" way to get it. EG saying $2+Q+Q$ is redundant when $1+Q+Q$ works. That makes it slightly easier to focus on what the key components are going to be.  $\quad$ Please also add the list of 10 winners. You can edit them into the problem directly, rather than leaving it as a comment.

Comment: I added the list of winners and yes you're right about the redundancy which was something I noticed later on.

Comment: Note that K+K+K is a huge waste, so there is likely a further optimization from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let the ranks be $R=\{0,\dots,13\}$, with "supply" $s_r=2$ if $r=0$ (two jokers) and $s_r=4$ otherwise.  Let $W$ be the set of $88$ possible winning hands $(i,j,k)\in R^3$, with $i \le j \le k$.  Let $d_{ijkr}\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ be the "demand" in hand $(i,j,k)$ for rank $r$, that is, the number of cards of rank $r$ among $\{i,j,k\}$.  Let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_{ijk}$ represent the number of copies of hand $(i,j,k)$ that are used.  The problem is to maximize $$\sum_{(i,j,k)\in W} x_{ijk}$$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{(i,j,k)\in W} d_{ijkr} x_{ijk} \le s_r \quad \text{for $r\in R$} \tag1\label1$$
The optimal objective value turns out to be $13$, attained by the following solution:
\begin{matrix}
i & j & k & \text{score} & x \\
\hline 
0 &13 &13 &31 &1 \\ 
3 &11 &11 &30 &2 \\
3 &12 &12 &32 &2 \\
5 &10 &10 &30 &2 \\
6 & 6 &13 &30 &2 \\
7 & 7 & 7 &31 &1 \\
7 & 9 & 9 &30 &1 \\
8 & 8 & 9 &30 &2 
\end{matrix}

The optimal dual variables of the linear programming relaxation provide a short certificate of optimality.  Explicitly, take $\pi_6=1/4$, $\pi_r=1/3$ for $r\in\{7,8,9\}$, and $\pi_r=1/2$ for $r\in\{10,11,12,13\}$.  Multiply \eqref{1} by $\pi_r$ and add them up to derive upper bound $$\sum_{(i,j,k)\in W} x_{ijk} \le \sum_{r\in R} \pi_r s_r = \frac{1}{4}\cdot4 + \frac{1}{3}(4+4+4) + \frac{1}{2}(4+4+4+4) = 13.$$

Comment: I got the same solution set as you. Are you able to tell if this is unique?

Comment: @CalvinLin There are 974 optimal solutions.

Answer (score 1):

(Skip below to see a proof that 13 is the maximum.)

In the comments, OP listed out ways to get a score of 30 or more.
At a quick glance, we can make 11 winners by taking the following combinations

- 7, 7, 7 (this is only single, the rest are paired)
- 9 9, 8
- 9, 9, 8
- 10, 10, 5
- 10, 10, 5
- J, J, 3
- J, J, 3
- Q, Q, 1
- Q, Q, 1
- K, K, 1
- K, K, 1

We can actually do better, getting up to 13 winner sets.

---

First, show that 13 can indeed be achieved. This is left to the reader.

Think of this as a structure-finder-and-avoider problem. As it turns out, the cards that are important to track are those with a value of 8 or more, of which there are 24 of these cards. The main idea we use is that, if the winner set each uses 2 or more of these 8+ cards, then there are at most 12 winner sets.
So, to get more than 12 winner sets, we need to find winner sets that use 0 or 1 of these 8+ cards. However, because there are too many of them, we also have to track the winner sets that use 3 of these 8+ cards.

From this train of reasoning, we make 2 observations that are crucial to the solution:

**Observation 1:**  Let's list out those winner sets which use 0 or 1 of these 8+ cards. We denote these as **restricted sets**.

- 0 8+ card: $7-7-7$
- 1 8+ card: $K-6-6$, $K-7-7$, $Q-7-7$, $J-7-7$.

**Observation 2:** Apart from $9-9-7$, any winner set with 9 will use 3 of these 8+ cards.

Now, we consider cases based on which of these restricted sets are formed by the winners.

Case 1: If the winner sets use none of these restricted sets, then

- Each winner set uses at least 2 8+ cards, so there are at most $  \lfloor \frac{24}{2} \rfloor = 12$ winners.

Case 2: If the winner sets does not use the $7-7-7$ restricted set, then

- If we use $ a \leq 2$ winner sets of the form $ $9-9-7$
  - If we use $b \leq 2 + \lfloor \frac{4-a} { 2} \rfloor $ winner sets with 1 8+ card   
  - If we use $ c \leq \lfloor \frac{4-2a} {3} \rfloor$ winner sets involving 9, 
  - then we have at most $ d = \lfloor \frac{ 24 - 2a - b - 3c } { 2 } \rfloor$ winer sets with 2 8+ cards. 
  - Show that $ a +b+c+d \leq 13$.

Case 3: If we use the $7-7-7$ restricted set, then

- If we use $ a \leq 1$ winner sets of the form $ $9-9-7$
  - If we use $b \leq 2 + \lfloor \frac{4-a} { 2} \rfloor $ winner sets with 1 8+ card   
  - If we use $ c \leq \lfloor \frac{4-2a} {3} \rfloor$ winner sets involving 9, 
  - then we have at most $ d = \lfloor \frac{ 24 - 2a - b - 3c } { 2 } \rfloor$ winer sets with 2 8+ cards. 
  - Show that $ a +b+c+d \leq 13$.

Hence, we have at most 13 winners sets, and this can be achieved. Thus, it is the maximum.

Comment: Can you explain what the equation means I'm not sure where you got those numbers from

Comment: Similar to 4 color map theorem : too many cases for vanilla computer program.  So, challenge is to refine computer program, and prove analytically that refinement is valid.

Comment: @user2661923 As it turns out, there is indeed a refinement that works.

Comment: To get $13$ winners, the nines need not be paired up twice, but you do need to use all four of the nines.

Comment: @RobPratt Ah thanks. Fixed the error.